# Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded

Tags: r, keras

I am new to R.
I am trying to do one hot coding  and am using `to_categorical` function and I am getting the error:

```
"Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded"
```

I have already installed keras package and have loaded it as well. Even tried removing it and installing again.

*This is my code:*

```
trainy <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainy)
```

I also tried the following code and got the same error:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
```

Please let me know if you require any other details!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to start menu / type "cmd" / open the command line / type "python --version" . What do you get?

Comment: i got the following 'python--version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: with a space inbetween `python --version`

Comment: tried it. got the same message :(

Comment: then you need to download and install Anaconda - NOT python. see my edits in the answer below, please also consider accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should either install Anaconda or add it to the path.
If the following:
go to start menu / type `cmd` / open the command line / type `python --version`
Doesn't give you something like:

```
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Then you need to install Conda: go [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and add it to your path after install by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/5224236) for detailed instructions

Comment: this worked. after installing Anaconda i ran the following code in R

install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow()

Comment: awesome, happy training